web socket server for steaming camera video
I have problem I can't share my camera video through websocket, I can't load both of page transmitter and receiver
I think I am not working well with open gcp cloud and their configuration, I need somoene who can guide me

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
